# How to define param names and types for a function which accepts 1 parameter or 2 parameters, in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to define a function, which provides two ways to call:

```
function visit(url: string, options: Partial<VisitOptions>): void
function visit(options: Partial<VisitOptions> & {url:string}): void
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to implement it.

Currently my code is:

```
type VisitOptions = {
  timeout: number
}

function visit(url: string, options: Partial<VisitOptions>): void;
function visit(options: Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string }): void;
function visit(...params: any): void {
  let finalOptions: Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string };
  if (params.length === 1) {
    finalOptions = params[0];
  } else {
    const [url, options] = params;
    finalOptions = {
      url,
      ...options
    }
  }
  console.log(finalOptions);
  // ... more
}
```

You can see in the real implementation function:

```
function visit(...params: any): void
```

I use `...params: any` as the parameter, it's working but I lose safe typing when I use it in function body.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: @downvoter: why downvote without any comment?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a union of tuples. You can then discriminate between the tuples using `length` as you already do. Basically all the types work out as you would expect them to and it is all type safe:

```
type VisitOptions = {
  timeout: number
}

function visit(url: string, options: Partial<VisitOptions>): void;
function visit(options: Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string }): void;
function visit(...params: [Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string }] | [string, Partial<VisitOptions>]): void {
  let finalOptions: Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string };
  if (params.length === 1) {
    finalOptions = params[0];
  } else {
    const [url, options] = params;
    finalOptions = {
      url,
      ...options
    }
  }
  console.log(finalOptions);
  // ... more
}
```